# Where are elevators located in aircraft with delta wings?

Tags: concorde, sr-71, delta-wing

Where were elevators located in aircraft with delta wings, notably the Concorde and the Blackbird SR-71?

If they didn't exist, how did these aircraft perform the nose up maneuver mid-air and at take off?  Why didn't they need elevators?

As mentioned in the comments:

While the other question is the same, the answers don't mention the distance between the CG/AC and the elevons (large moment) nor the stabilizing effect of the long delta wing (or the presence of canards on the TU-144). So there is room to improve it.

Comment: Between floor 1 and 5?

Comment: If you think that there is the need for more details on the other question's answers, you can put a bounty on it. If you think there are more questions to be answered, you can edit your own to be specificallly about something that is not mentioned in those answers.

Comment: They used combinations of elevators and ailerons, called "elevons", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevon.